# Accessing private member variables of a class from a static method

Tags: c++, static-methods, private-members

I am able to access the private member variable of the class shown in below code directly using an object instance (pointer to object). As per my understanding private members should not be accessible. Can someone please help to explain the reason behind this behaviour ?

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass;
using myClassPtr = std::shared_ptr<myClass>;

class myClass {
public:
    myClass(unsigned int val) : m_val(val) {}
    ~myClass() {}

    static
    myClassPtr create(unsigned int val) {
        myClassPtr objPtr = nullptr;
        objPtr = std::make_shared<myClass>(val);
        if(objPtr) {
            std::cout << objPtr->m_val << std::endl;
        }
        return objPtr;
    }
private:
    unsigned int m_val;
};

int main () {
    myClassPtr objPtr = myClass::create(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
anandkrishnr@anandkrishnr-mbp cpp % g++ static_test.cc -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror
anandkrishnr@anandkrishnr-mbp cpp % ./a.out
10
```

Comment: You've almost certainly duplicated a question (or ten...) with this, but someone new to C++ isn't going to be able to both use the proper search terms to find them and then know from search summaries which search result(s) are likely to answer this question.

Comment: Private members of a class can be accessed in class functions. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access.

Comment: @Andrew Henle can you please share here which question it duplicates so that it can be helpful :)

Comment: That helped @Deev .

The name of every class member (static, non-static, function, type, etc) has an associated "member access". When a name of the member is used anywhere a program, its access is checked, and if it does not satisfy the access rules, the program does not compile

Since the static functions is also a member function its able to access the member variable. This make sense.

Comment: No luck finding a duplicate, but found some related questions: [How can a public static member function access private instance member variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544991), [Can a Static method access a private method of the same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144979/), and [Why can I access static member variables inside a static callback method without an instance variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57731822/)

Comment: @JaMiT [**Can a Static method access a private method of the same class?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144979/can-a-static-method-access-a-private-method-of-the-same-class), Some language-agnostic discussion here: [**Why is a private member accessible in a static method?**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246633/why-is-a-private-member-accessible-in-a-static-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static myClassPtr create(unsigned int val) {
```

`create()` is a static method of `myClass`, it is a member of this class. As such it it entitled to access all private members and methods of its class. This right extends not only to its own class instance, but ***any*** instance of this class.

> As per my understanding private members should not be accessible.

... except by members of their class.

Let's create a completely pointless copy constructor for your class, the same copy constructor you would get by default:

```
myClass(const myClass &o) : m_val{o.m_val} {}
```

This copy constructor has no issues, whatsoever, of accessing `m_val` of the passed-in object. Exactly the same thing happens here. `m_val` is a private member of its class. It doesn't mean that only an instance of the same exact object can access its private members, it means that ***any*** instance of the class, or a static class method, can access the private class members.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of access modifiers on a class is to restrict the use of a class's members *outside* of that class.

Since `create()` is inside `myClass`, `create()` is allowed to access any private members (or really any members) of `myclass` that you have declared. including `m_val`

For example, lets make a simple class,

if you had the code:

```
class box {
private:
    int width;
    int height;
};
int main() {
    box b;
    b.width;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler would throw the error:
`error C2248: 'box::width': cannot access private member declared in class 'box'`

Because the `main()` function is declared outside of the class, therefore, the `main()` function is not allowed to access private members of the class `box`.

If we wanted to access, say the width, outside of that class, we would need to then make those members public to allow everything else in the program to see those members:

```
class box {
private:
    int width;
    int height;
public:
    int pubWidth;
    int pubHeight;
};
int main() {
    box b;
    b.pubWidth;

    return 0;
}
```

This time, the members we are trying to access are public, (`pubWidth`) allowing outside functions, classes, etc. from accessing these members of `box`

Programiz in my opinion, has a great, easy to understand article about access modifiers in c++. I would reccommend giving it a look. link [here](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/access-modifiers).

Little note: If not specified, all members in a class are private with the exception of constructors, destructors, and maybe some special use-cases I can't think of off the top of my head.

hope this clears it up!